# Character encoding of SSIS package changing while saving it in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, encoding, ssis, sql-server-2014

When i try to save my SSIS package in visual studio i am getting below error message

*The character encoding for the file ... has changed. Your source control provider may have problems managing files with this type of encoding. For example, if you save an ANSI-encoded file as UTF-8 you may not be able to merge or show differences.*

MY SSIS package is encoded in Windows -1252.

See the error message here-
[Visual studio - Character encoding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geob0.jpg)

And when we ignored the message and tried to simply proceed with saving the update package, the following warnings appear to anyone else who open the same project which contains the updated package

*Warning 1 - Warning loading BI_ENGINEERING_DW.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node. Verify that the project was created by the same user. Project load will attempt to continue without the encrypted information.

Warning 2 - Warning loading BI_ENGINEERING_DW.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt sensitive data in project with a user key. You may not be the user who encrypted this project, or you are not using the same machine that was used to save the project. If the sensitive data is a parameter value, the value may be required to run the package on the Integration Services server.*

See the error message here-
[Warning - Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtQQa.png)